# Android dynamic feature stuck at installing view although it says it is installed

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-module, dynamic-feature-module

I use dynamic feature module in my app and here is my `App` class -

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class DogApp : SplitCompatApplication() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        SplitCompat.install(this)
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity` -

```
private var sessionId: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        fetchModules()
    }

    private fun fetchModules() {
        val splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this)

        val request = SplitInstallRequest
            .newBuilder()
            .addModule("dogProfile")
            .build()

        val listener =
            SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener { splitInstallSessionState ->
                if (splitInstallSessionState.sessionId() == sessionId) {
                    when (splitInstallSessionState.status()) {
                        SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED -> {
                            Log.e("hi", "Installed")
                        }
                        SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING -> {
                            val totalBytes = splitInstallSessionState.totalBytesToDownload()
                            val progress = splitInstallSessionState.bytesDownloaded()
                            Log.e("hi", "Downloading$totalBytes...$progress")
                        }
                        SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING -> {
                            Log.e("hi", "Installing")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        splitInstallManager.registerListener(listener)

        splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("hi", "Exception: $e") }
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.e("hi", "Success")
                sessionId = it
                val navHostFragment =
                    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
                navHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.id.homeView)
            }
    }
```

When I build the apk and run on my device/emulator, I see "Installing Module" that stays forever
and I see the logs -

```
Installed

Success
```

Here is the screen I see forever -

[image]

What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: dynamic feature module doesn't come with UI. So how are you seeing this screen?

Comment: When I choose Run -> Edit Configurations -> Deploy APK from app bundle and run the app on emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use navigation `2.3.2`? I found there is an issue after [this change](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169636207#comment3). Rollback to `2.3.1` or use your own progress UI instead of `DefaultProgressFragment` will fix this issue.

Comment: great! this fixed my issue but I get an error now - 

SplitInstallService : Failed to bind to the service.
DynamicInstallManager: Error requesting install of MyApp.dogProfile: Failed to bind to the service.
DefaultProgressFragment: Installation failed with error -100

Comment: It depends on how you test DFM. If you don't use `FakeSplitInstallManager` then the best way to test DFM flow is to upload to [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679)